# error with the bootstrap tooltip on drupal 7 site : TOOLTIP: Option "animation" provided type "number" but expected type "boolean"

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, drupal-7, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have the following error

TOOLTIP: Option "animation" provided type "number" but expected type "boolean"

I have tried to trace the error but couldn't tell from where it starts or how to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an error in popover or tooltip component.

How to find and fix this.

1. Search your code for keyword `animation`.
2. Check what is the value of it animation. As docs (and your error) says its value should be a boollean, but you have provide a number. It should be either `true` or `false`
3. Change the number to either true or false. This should fix the error.

Sample code :

```
$('#example').popover({
 animation: true /* it should NOT be a number or string */
})
```

Comment: The issue is this is not my code I think it is because of a script from drupal, that's why I don't know where it is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to disable the tooltip and popover options from the drupal bootstrap settings.